# Вывести дерево в файл формата .dot

Tags: дерево, c++

Нужно вывести дерево в файл формата .dot, как?
Вот мой код:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct Tree{

    int value ;
    struct Tree *left ;
    struct Tree *right ;

};

struct Tree *BTree(struct Tree *root, struct Tree *r, int value){

    if(!r){

        r = new struct Tree ;

        r -> left = NULL;
        r -> right = NULL ;
        r -> value = value ;

        if(!root){
            return r ;
        }

        if(value > root -> value ){
            root -> left = r ;
        }else{
            root -> right = r ;
        }

        return r ;

    }

    if (value < r -> value){
        BTree (r, r->left, value) ;
    }else{
        BTree (r, r->right, value) ;
    }

}

int main(){

    ifstream Object ;
    Object.open ("2.txt") ;
    struct Tree *rt = NULL ;

    int tmp ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 7 ; i++){
        Object >> tmp ;
        rt= BTree (rt, rt, tmp) ;
    }

    return 0 ;

}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: @Якоби, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Я считываю из файла элементы дерева, делаю дерево, не знаю, как записать в файл.dot. Хочу, чтобы нагляднее было. Учебное задание мной уже выполнено.

Comment: Идёте на сайт graphiz, смотрите примеры - profit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dot файл выглядит очень просто. Первой строкой нужно написать такое

```
digraph G{
```

где G - это просто имя, туда можно вписать нужный идентификатор, но его глубокий смысл мне не известен. Дальше записываются пары "родитель" - "Наследник". Их список Вам известен, его можно получить, пройдясь по всему дереву. Порядок записи не важен. Формат следующий.

```
"parent"->"child";
```

и в самом конце нужна закрывающая скобка.

Итого. Обычно файл будет где то такой

```
digraph G{
   "1"->"2";
   "2"->"3";
   "2"->"4";
}
```

И последняя подсказка. Как выводить в файл - для этого нужно ofstream. Пример кода

```
#include <fstream>      // std::ofstream

int main () {
  // node - это просто вектор с списком ребер.
  // тут нужно вставить его инициализацию
  std::ofstream ofs;
  ofs.open ("test.dot", std::ofstream::out);

  ofs << "digraph G{" << std::endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < node.size; i++) {
    ofs << "\"" << node[i].parent << "\"->\"" << node[i].child << "\";" << std::endl;
  }
  ofs << "}" << std::endl;

  ofs.close();

  return 0;
}
```